# Apply prop.table function to list elements in R

Tags: r, functional-programming, lapply

I have created a series of tables in a list in R that I would like to run prop.test on in R. I'm trying to run proportion tests on a number large number of dummy variables in a large dataset. I created the tables as follows:

`<- colnames(mydata[, 1:100])
t <- lapply(c, function(i) {
table(mydata$treatment, mydata[, i])
})`

Now I want to apply the function prop.test to each of the tables in the list generated by the previous code:

```
p <- lapply(c, function(d) {prop.test(t[[d]])})
```

But this doesn't seem to work. However,

`prop.test(t[[1]])`

Does give me the proportion test for the first table in the list.

Any thoughts??

Comment: Your second `lapply` could just be `p <- lapply(t, prop.test)`.  The problem might be that the names of the list elements are not being carried across during the `table` operation - so you can't refer to the elements of `t` by the names of `c`.

Comment: When I try that I get the error `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 'x' must have 2 columns`

Comment: It sounds as if one of your tables has more than two columns - i.e. there is a `mydata[,i]` with more than two factor levels. The problem could be `NA`s - perhaps try `useNA="no"` in the call to `table`.

Comment: (1) Please provide some minimal sample data and expected output by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49308178/edit) your post. (2) The first code chunk is not valid R code (the line starting with `<- ...`); please check and edit your post.